# Cannot write to file (mysql command)

Tags: mysql

I logged in mysql, the user i used have File_priv but i can not write file to webroot

```
(select 123 into outfile '/var/www/html/webroot') 
==> error: Can't create/write to file '/var/www/html/webroot/abc.txt' (Errcode: 13)
```

Have any way to bypass this test case?

Hope everyone help, thank you!

Comment: maybe permission problem .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving full right to file.
chmod -r 777 abc.txt

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the webroot permissions are set to writable.